# queryselector none when I ask for an input value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

```
  const searchQuery=document.querySelector('#searchQ').value
  const p=document.querySelector('p')
  const log= (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(searchQuery)
    p.innerHTML=`${searchQuery}`
    fetchData()
  }
```

This is the part of my code in the React app that gives me the error, in particular the first line. the #searchQ is a normal HTTML input field that should start a get request, and `fetchData()` is a normal fetch API function and it's working properly. that way it gives me this error:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
> App
> src/App.js:5
> 5 |   let searchQuery=document.querySelector('#searchQ').value

when I remove the .value it runs normally but of course, it won't fetch the user's input. I tried let instead of const. Also I took the code in a vanilla js, HTML page and it logged successfully, but the same method doesn't work in react.
Any help?

Comment: it's a bad practice to use `querySelector` in react like apps. use `ref` to grab the values.

Comment: Did you try console logging the document.querySelector('#searchQ'), is it even rendered before you are utilizing it?
Also, would be great if you can provide a minimal reproducible URL of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered as a top rated bad practice to use `querySelector()` or `getElementById()` except for some specific cases, however in this case you can get to work with `useEffect` as you need to **wait** for the component to mount.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchQuery = document.querySelector("#searchQ").value;
    console.log(searchQuery);
  }, []);
```

A **Better** version would be

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const pRef = useRef();
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    pRef.current.innerHTML = value;

    console.log(value);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={value} id="searchQ" onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
      <p ref={pRef}></p>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In react u don't directly load the components just as normal HTML. It uses the render() method and there querySelector method doesn't work.

Either use state to directly control/retrieve the value or use ref as @boxdob said.